# Ssh and screen makes my process dormant on linux small pod

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, display

I have a process that runs inside screen and I connect to the server via ssh to see what is being written by the process. Once in a while, when I'm connected and I don't disconnect manually the process will froze and do nothing for a few hours until I reconnect again with ssh and screen -rd mysession.
I already tried logging with screen what happens and nothings comes out:

```
ESC[32mMy **MaxMin: ***ESC[39m
ESC[32m***ESC[39m
```

while my internal logging does show the time gap:

```
[2021-02-23 03:29:12] middle.INFO: My ** MaxMin: ***
[2021-02-23 11:05:16] middle.INFO: ***
```

I already tried using nonblock on and the logging to find out what is going on with no improvment.
Does anyone have a better suggerence on how to find what the issue is?
I strongly believe that it is related to screen because it is happening around the hour I go to sleep so a faulty ssh might be the culprit. But I still don't have any proof to back this up.
I'm using a lot of ram and cpu but not 8 hours of processing time. It could also be a network call with long timeout in this case, but I have seen it do the blackout without any network call between the two loggings (I will check my timeouts in the meanwhile).

edit: It could be copy mode but I have been unable to replicate it intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the shell is blocking the process when you lose the connection. This can happen if the process is in foreground since the process will be attached to the stdin/stdout and screen will try to keep the connection live. This can lead toward blocking of the process.

When you lose connection, the foreground process will receive SIGPIPE signal. I assume that screen will try to mask it similar to what nohup is doing for SIGHUP.

If you don't need to interact with the process, try running it as a background process in the screen's shell with `&`.